# Test code coverage for Batch Apex Constructor

Tags: apex, batch, code-coverage

Source  : [Please check this link about test class coverage for batch apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_batch_2.htm)

**My Requirement** : What they doing is they having **argument contructor** on batch apex. like

```
 global class CleanUpRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{

         global CleanUpRecords(string query){    //argument constructor

            query = '.............';
         }
   ......
  }
```

for the above argument constructor they did test code coverage like below,

```
           string query = '..........';
           Test.startTest();
           CleanUpRecords c = new CleanUpRecords(query);
           Database.executeBatch(c);
           Test.stopTest();
```

But for my scenario I have **default constructor(no-argument constructor
)**. So, How do I use above method to cover my default constructor. for example my construct is like,

```
global class CleanUpRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{

    global string query;
             global CleanUpRecords(){    //no-argument constructor

                  query = '.............';
             }
       ......
      }
```

Any help is appreciable. Thanks!!

Azar

Answer (score 1):

It is virtually the same...you just call the constructor you have.

```
Test.startTest();
CleanUpRecords c = new CleanUpRecords(); //<-- invoke constructor without argument
Database.executeBatch(c);
Test.stopTest();
```

By not providing the argument, the no-args constructor will be invoked.

If you had both, then you'd probably want to create two test methods (one for each constructor) to ensure that each gets coverage.

Comment: I tried the same one but no improvement in code coverage!

Comment: That's curious. Normally, this is all you would need to do to invoke the constructor. Are you certain this is the part that is not getting code coverage?

Comment: ok I got my coverage to 87%. Some of the conditions are not coverable in test class so I used seeAllData=true annotation and set up records that satisfy those conditions.

Comment: So is it a question of the query not returning any data? If so, there may be some work arounds. I think you should add some more details...maybe someone can help and you can avoid `SeeAllData=true`.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen what did you do to increase your coverage? I'm seeing the same issue.